# C# Winforms App - Not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am receiving this error - Not a valid Win32 Application. The program runs fine on a Vista PC. It is deployed using the ClickOnce bootstrapper. ]

I read

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx

here that VS2012 ClickOnce does not support XP, but this article is focused on C++, not C#. I can't see anything similar for C#.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you build it in 64-bit? Good chance the Vista is a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Agree with MrFox, right click the solution and see the projects how they are compiled, alternatively check the properties of each project and change the build

Comment: The vista PC is 32 bit. The solution is being compiled as 32 bit as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your source states:

> Clickonce bootstrapper engine (setup.exe) that was shipped with Visual Studio 2012 is NOT compatible with any OS below Windows Vista.  So, the above error message is expected and by design. The reason for this behavior is because the bootstrapper is compiled using the VC compiler and the Dev11 VC compiler does not support Windows XP.

That applies to any application compiled with VS2012, regardless of language, because it's the bootstrapper (install program) that's failing, not the application.

So your **application** can run on the XP box, but not the Clickonce installer.

Comment: So if I install http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update (I cannot find a working link to CTP 3), recompile the application should install using the setup.exe file?

Comment: further to this, I cannot find the platform toolset option that is in the screenshot. Im going to the properties of the solution, then there is far fewer options that whats in the screenshot. Thanks

Comment: @MattBaughan - Try it?  The first service pack for VS2012 added windows xp desktop support.  In the end if you want to support Windows XP you might have to NOT use ClickOnce to do so.

Comment: Looks like the update to VS 2012 worked. I can now install the application using the setup.exe on a Windows XP PC. THanks for the help!